# Android animate width on touch

Tags: android, animation

I want to animate a view's width on the swipe of `ViewPager` (Scale a button on the screen).
I'm using the following function to animate the width:

```
fun View.animateWidth(targetWidth: Int, duration) {
     val prevWidth = width

     visibility = View.VISIBLE
     val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(prevWidth, targetWidth)
     valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
         layoutParams.width = animation.animatedValue as Int
         this@animateWidth.requestLayout()
     }
     valueAnimator.duration = duration
     valueAnimator.start()
}
```

I'm calling this function on every update that I'm getting from `onPageScrollListener` of my `ViewPager`. The problem is that the UI is not getting updated until either I stop touching/ moving my fingers or I get to the next page of the screen. It seems that the UI is blocking my animation until I finish my touch moves.
Any idea?

Edit: This is where I call the `animateWidth` function:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {}
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            button.animateWidth(
                    (fullWidth * positionOffset).toInt(), 1)
        }
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {  }
    })
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of where you are using `View.animateWidth`.

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov I've added the code snippet